# How to construct complex sentence (with reasons) using neither and nor.

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I would like to write a complex sentence using *neither* and *nor*.

For example:

This method is neither fast, as it requires long times to give the result, nor simple as it requires three main challenges steps.

Is this a correct way to use neither and nor with a sentence includes reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a little awkward, but not incorrect (though I think you need a comma before the second “as”).

Comment: Definitely yes to @Josh's suggestion that a comma is needed before both 'as it ...' phrases. Also I think there is a typo in that the words 'challenges' and 'steps' are not both needed - one of those two should be deleted.